# android How to add quantity in the shopping cart?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, cart

Hello I hope you are able to understand me, my English is not good, sorry
, I have an `activity` that contains a `listview` of products,if you click is added to another activity shopping cart. So far so good. I have gotten that if you click 2 times an article, 2 same items will not be added in the shopping cart, but now I want to establish a method to show me the same item if I pressed 2 times, exit 2 in the quantity field , and the price multiply by two, logically.

So insert the clicked item in the cart activity:
I created a variable that counts how many times an item was clicked,(contador)

```
case 0:
if (page1 == null)
{
       page1 = (ListView) LayoutInflater.from(Local_mostrar_bebidaActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.page_one_viewpager_listview, null);
       page1.setAdapter(adapterlistvMenuBEBIDAS);
       page1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)                                  {
       ItemListView item = itemsListVMenuBEBIDAS.get(position);
       if (MiPedidoActivity.itemsListVMiPedido.contains(item)) { // <- look for item!
       // ... item already in list
               Log.i(LOGTAG, "Añadido item "+ contador+" "+ numUds);
               ++contador;
               numUds=contador;
    } 
        else {
               MiPedidoActivity.itemsListVMiPedido.add(item);
               contador= 1;
               numUds=contador;
               Log.i(LOGTAG, "Añadido item "+ contador+" "+ numUds);
         }});
}
page = page1;
break;
```

I so add the products in the `arraylist`

```
private static ArrayList<ItemListView> obtenerItemsMenuBEBIDAS() {
    ArrayList<ItemListView> itemsMenuBEBIDAS = new ArrayList<ItemListView>();

    itemsMenuBEBIDAS.add(new ItemListView(1, "Product1", "malta y z.", "drawable/a1","3.10",""+numUds));

    itemsMenuBEBIDAS.add(new ItemListView(3, "Cocacola", "Botellin de 22ml","drawable/cocacola_logo","1.75",""+ numUds));
    itemsMenuBEBIDAS.add(new ItemListView(4, "Cocacola Zero", "Botellin de 22ml","drawable/cocacola_zero","1.75",""+ numUds ));

    return itemsMenuBEBIDAS;
}
```

(numUds) is a variable that I have created to know how many units have been clicked and then display the corresponding `textview`

Any idea?

Comment: what does this mean , exit 2 in the quantity field , and the price multiply by two, logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're declaring both 'numUds' and 'contador' variables, but they seem to be variables for your Activity class, not for each item in the list.

You seem to have a class called `ItemListView` that represent each object in the list. In that class you must have a property that keeps track of the number of units ('numUds' maybe) **for each object**. This way you can increment the count variable like this:

```
ItemListView item = itemsListVMenuBEBIDAS.get(position);
item.numUds ++;
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I will try this solution and tell if it worked. But I think you have the right answer. Thanks for helping

Comment: this was perfect for me ! Thanks